# Java - Map.remove not actually removing

Tags: java, oop, dictionary, collections, equals

I have a `Vector2d` object with private members `x` and `y`.
It has the `equals` function:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof Vector2d))
        return false;
    Vector2d other = (Vector2d) o;
    return this.x == other.getX() && this.y == other.getY();
}
```

I have a `Map<Vector2d, Tile>` and I want to remove any entry that has a certain position. Here's my method where I want to do that:

```
public void placeTile(Tile tile, double tileX, double tileY) {
    Vector2d pos = new Vector2d(tileX, tileY);
    // overwrite
    this.tiles.remove(pos);
    for (Vector2d v : new HashSet<>(this.tiles.keySet())) {
        if (pos.equals(v))
            this.tiles.remove(v);
    }
    this.tiles.put(new Vector2d(tileX, tileY), tile);
}
```

Now the odd thing is that `this.tiles.remove(pos)` does not work - it doesn't actually remove the `Tile` with that position. However, the loop works.
Any ideas what could cause this behavior? It is like the `HashMap` is not using the implemented `equals`. Thank you

Comment: This almost certainly indicates you don't have a correct `hashCode` implementation.  Did you override `hashCode` like you need to?

Comment: if using a `HashMap`.... (`hashCode()` (and then `equals`) is used to locate an element)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override `hashCode()` as well as `equals()` as the HashMap indexes keys using the hashcode.

```
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(x, y);
    }
```